# Is there a way to enforce an unlock pin only if it has been locked remotely via device admin?

Tags: android, device-admin

If a user has not set a device unlock pin then I am assuming that she doesn't want the pain of unlocking it everytime the screen goes to sleep(even though its a security risk). Here, usability wins over security and I'm sure there might be many people doing this.

However, I am trying to write an app so that in case the phone gets lost, it can be locked remotely and could be unlocked only via a user pin. Now this is a catch 22 situation.

I am wondering if there is a way that a user(thief) has to unlock the phone by entering a pin only if it has been locked remotely via Device Admin? I am ok if its a one time manual effort setting that PIN from user side via my app during its installation.

Is it possible using the android SDK, somehow? Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

yes i guess you can do this using [this package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/package-summary.html)

sorry but i have not had chance to use it to guide you further.